How to get user's location data as longitude and latitude on backend server?
I'm coding backend server of an android project. I'm using spring boot. They wanted me to get location data from user (every hour automaticly, with location server of android device) in backend. I dont have access to frontend and I found many ways for do that in frontend. I have to get location data from device, then save it to db.  I setted geolocation, it can convert longitude and latitude to address automaticly, but that longitude and latitude data should be in db. Is it possible to do that in backend?
I couldnt find a way yet.

But in any ways android application will send these lat lng
